# Wiremock using certificate not working on Windows

Tags: wiremock, kotlintest, kotest

This error only happens on the Windows OS. On Linux and MacOS it works fine.

I've made sure that the password for the certificates is correct, that they do exist in the mentioned location and that the port is available.
Language is Kotlin. Testing framework is Kotest.

Certificates are under:
test/resources/ssl-certs/client-cert.p12
test/resources/ssl-certs/server-cert.p12

```
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.RequestMethod
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.ContainsPattern
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.RequestPatternBuilder.newRequestPattern
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.UrlPattern
import my.test.library.apigee.bankingapi.BankingApiApigeePropertiesFixtures.bankingApiApigeeProperties
import my.test.library.apigee.bankingapi.testutils.mockServer
import io.kotest.assertions.withClue
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.StringSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import java.net.URI

class ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest : StringSpec({

    val sslServerPort = 10443

    val apigeeMockServer = mockServer {
        httpDisabled(true)
        httpsPort(sslServerPort)
        keystorePath(ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest::class.java.getResource("/ssl-certs/server-cert.p12").path)
        keystoreType("pkcs12")
        keystorePassword("wiremock-truststore-password")
        keyManagerPassword("wiremock-truststore-password")

        needClientAuth(true)
        trustStorePath(ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest::class.java.getResource("/ssl-certs/client-cert.p12").path)
        trustStorePassword("ssl-password")
        trustStoreType("pkcs12")
    }

    beforeSpec {
        apigeeMockServer.stubFor(
            get("/some-url").willReturn(
                aResponse().withStatus(200)
            )
        )
    }

    val sut = ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilder(
        bankingApiApigeeProperties(
            url = "https://localhost:$sslServerPort",
            sslCertificateURL = "/ssl-certs/client-cert.p12",
            sslCertificatePassword = "ssl-password"
        )
    )

    "#buildSSlRequestFactory" {

        withClue("ssl configuration is used") {
            val request = sut.buildSSlRequestFactory().createRequest(URI.create("https://localhost:$sslServerPort/some-url"), HttpMethod.GET)

            val response = request.execute()

            response.statusCode shouldBe HttpStatus.OK

            apigeeMockServer.verify(
                newRequestPattern(RequestMethod.GET, UrlPattern(ContainsPattern("/some-url"), false))
            )
        }
    }
})
```

The error I'm getting (only on Windows):

```
14:09:46.196 [qtp1976741669-37] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - ignored: WriteFlusher@1502467f{IDLE}->null
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0000029A3CD9AFE8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000c0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE (..\ssl\tls13_both.cc:324 00007FFD46C71BC0:0x00000000)

.
.
.
.


Process finished with exit code -1

Software caused connection abort: recv failed
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:839)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.executeInternal(BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.java:63)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at my.test.library.apigee.bankingapi.certificates.ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest$1$2.invokeSuspend(ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest.kt:57)
    at my.test.library.apigee.bankingapi.certificates.ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest$1$2.invoke(ApigeeSslConnectionFactoryBuilderTest.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$executeWithBehaviours$2$1.invokeSuspend(executions.kt:16)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$executeWithBehaviours$2$1.invoke(executions.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt.wrapTestWithGlobalAssert(executions.kt:43)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$executeWithBehaviours$2.invokeSuspend(executions.kt:15)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$executeWithBehaviours$2.invoke(executions.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$wrapTestWithAssertionModeCheck$2.invokeSuspend(executions.kt:29)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt$wrapTestWithAssertionModeCheck$2.invoke(executions.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.test.AssertionModeKt.executeWithAssertionsCheck(AssertionMode.kt:39)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt.wrapTestWithAssertionModeCheck(executions.kt:28)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutionsKt.executeWithBehaviours(executions.kt:14)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1$3$1.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:195)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1$3$1.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:194)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1$3.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:189)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1$3.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ReplayKt.replay(replay.kt:19)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:184)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1$1.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturnIgnoreTimeout(Undispatched.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.setupTimeout(Timeout.kt:120)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.withTimeout(Timeout.kt:37)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:183)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2$1.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutorExecutionContext$executeWithTimeoutInterruption$$inlined$suspendCoroutine$lambda$2.invokeSuspend(ExecutorExecutionContext.kt:47)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.ExecutorExecutionContext.executeWithTimeoutInterruption-D5N0EJY(ExecutorExecutionContext.kt:46)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:182)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$executeAndWait$2.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturnIgnoreTimeout(Undispatched.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.setupTimeout(Timeout.kt:120)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.withTimeout(Timeout.kt:37)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.executeAndWait(TestCaseExecutor.kt:180)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.invokeTestCase(TestCaseExecutor.kt:149)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.executeActiveTest(TestCaseExecutor.kt:118)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$intercept$2.invokeSuspend(TestCaseExecutor.kt:69)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor$intercept$2.invoke(TestCaseExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.executeIfActive(TestCaseExecutor.kt:83)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.intercept(TestCaseExecutor.kt:69)
    at io.kotest.core.runtime.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.kt:50)
    at io.kotest.core.engine.SingleInstanceSpecRunner.runTest(SingleInstanceSpecRunner.kt:61)
    at io.kotest.core.engine.SingleInstanceSpecRunner$execute$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$invoke$lambda$1.invokeSuspend(SingleInstanceSpecRunner.kt:71)
    at io.kotest.core.engine.SingleInstanceSpecRunner$execute$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$invoke$lambda$1.invoke(SingleInstanceSpecRunner.kt)
    at io.kotest.core.engine.SpecRunner$runParallel$$inlined$map$lambda$2$1.invokeSuspend(SpecRunner.kt:78)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at io.kotest.core.engine.SpecRunner$runParallel$$inlined$map$lambda$2.run(SpecRunner.kt:77)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
    ... 91 more
```